# xUnit Test- all test not running on Azure when using yml configuration

Tags: c#, azure, unit-testing, xunit

I have a .NET application using .NET Framework 4.7 that includes the xUnit unit testing framework.
The application and unit test execute as expected from my local dev environment and from Azure using a .net solution build.

I recently added another build based on a yml file to Azure that is building the same code and executing the same unit tests, 
however, the number of unit tests being executed with the yml configuration are vastly different and nearly half of the unit test are not executed when using the yml configuration. The yml file is super simple that is the first place I started my troubleshooting efforts and will be glad to share if needed.

Review of the test results between the solution build versus the yml build indicated the following warning that is only in the yml unit test results:

```
Warning 5/14/2020 1:46:33 PM    [MSTest][Discovery][d:\a\1\s\src\OTEMS\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.2.1.0\build\netcoreapp1.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll] Unable to load types from the test source 'd:\a\1\s\src\OTEMS\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.2.1.0\build\netcoreapp1.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll'. Some or all of the tests in this source may not be discovered.
Error: System.TypeLoadException: Method 'get_DataRow' in type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.TestContextImplementation' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' does not have an implementation.
```

Note the `\netcoreapp1.0\` in the path. This warning only occurs with the yml variation but the project is NOT a .net core build, and I can't seem to find where this is being referenced or if it is the actual problem.

Comment: You asked about `xUnit`, but your error tells about `MSTest` and `MSTestAdapter`

Comment: This project has 3 unit tests that were written using MSTest and all the remaining unit tests are xUnit tests. The 3 MSTest are successfully being executed when running the yml build, it is a portion of the (aprox 210) xUnit tests that are not being executed. When executing the build using solution file instead of the yml, all the tests (both the MSTest and xUnit test) are being executed.